# ADT cannot find emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, emulation

I have been using eclipse adt for android development. But now all of a sudden eclipse does not recognise the sdk folder.It says it cannot find the emulator.
I am using ubuntu 12.04. Here is a screen shot of the IDE. How can I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: have u update your adt

Comment: yes,i just uploaded the adt. And i also installed android studio,can it be the problem?

Comment: first u uninstall adt and install adt